# clustering MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, cluster, database-administration, rdbms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sql server active/passive vs active/active clustering](https://serverfault.com/questions/255888/sql-server-active-passive-vs-active-active-clustering)

I have a Project in DBMS just I need something like a BIG TITLES of What TO DO.

Here a brief way about the Project:

1. Install 3 WIN2K8 R2 one of them domain controller (easy)
2. On non DC nodes, install SQL as clustered node.use passive /active. (Inexplicable)
3. Use a client to test the enviroment (easy)

Just the step 2 I need some Info.

Any Idea will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information on MSDN about creating a SQL Server cluster:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179530.aspx

If you are not comfortable with Windows clustering and how to configure, I would suggest that you might want to seek out some additional training.